# Inconsistencies in data retrieval from csv file

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, csv, data-binding

I am developing my personal project using Visual Studio 12. Coding in ASP.net using C#.

When I retrieve data from a csv file and display it on a chart, it shows that the total number of records pulled and displayed is 160. 
Then I go to the csv file and search using the same filter that I had done initially. The result that I get back is 458 records.

So what I don't seem to understand is how come I get 160 using linq to pull data off a csv and 458 records when I search in excel straight away.

This is the linq code that Im using:

```
var myfavitems = collection_of_objects.Where(a => a.GotCar == "1").ToList();
            foreach (var t in myfavitems.GroupBy(a => a.Metal_Type))
            {
             Do something/ display on graph
            }
```

Could someone please guide me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are 458 distinct metal types (regardless of their composition). And yes I did a manual groupby to the file which gave me 458 aswell. But as soon as I apply that code, the answer completely changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having totally 458 items. And 160 groups of items by metal type in those 458 items. To verify:

```
var myfavitems = collection_of_objects.Where(a => a.GotCar == "1").ToList();

// let us know this value. is this 458?
int totalItemsCount = myfavitems.Count;

var groupedItems = myfavitems.GroupBy(a => a.Metal_Type);

// let us know this value. is this 160?
int totalGroupsOnChart = groupedItems.Keys.Count();

foreach (var t in groupedItems)
{
 // Do something/ display on graph
}
```

Comment: totalItemsCount give me 160 and totalGroupsOnChart give me 2. I think I'm going to rewrite my code for pulling the data just incase. Nevertheless thanks for your answer Raja. Much appreciated.

Comment: what is the value for collection_of_objects.Count()?

Comment: 16000 is what I get including where gotcar == "0". Also I have found why it was spitting out incorrect results. It was because the csv file had commas in two columns which meant that it had extra two columns. Now I have removed the commas and the answers that are spitted out are correct

Comment: wht is this filter that you applied? "Then I go to the csv file and search using the same filter that I had done initially. The result that I get back is 458 records."